# Ambari Freezes on Install complete (Waiting to start)

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Logs show no warnings or fails.

All nodes are frozen on `Install complete (Waiting to start)` status.

It has been like this for ~20 hours.

[image]

It might have something to do with the increased timeouts (x10) I set by running

`grep -rl "</timeout>" /var/lib/ambari-server/ | xargs sed -i 's/<\/timeout>/0<\/timeout>/g'`

Any ideas?

Comment: I've had this happen before... I know that I had to do like `ps aux` and maybe grep that for ambari or something... I then `kill -9` some process, then it continued... Sorry I can't be more specific than that. It might have something to do with waiting for the namenode

Comment: mmh, ok but on the server or the nodes?

Comment: The nodes are servers. Explain?

Comment: Basically, it is waiting for communication with something to continue its operations. If I recall correctly, all you've done in identify the hostnames, the SSH keys, the services you want,  their configs, etc. Basically, if you configure some networking setting wrong in there, Ambari will hang as it constantly times out

Comment: *ambari-server,  *cluster-nodes (ambari-agent processes)

Comment: Could be either, honestly. You might be able to find some useful information in `/var/log` for some Ambari logs on the Ambari server

Comment: I am trying that and also the API rest but nothing so far

Comment: my fear is: If I kill the server process, does the cluster disappear and I have to start all over again? Because that happened to me some other time, and it took almost 5 hours to get to that 33%...

Comment: Last line in the ambari server log is "Nothing to do for service check as could not find role or or host to run check on, clusterName=CLUSTER_SG, serviceName=ELASTICSEARCH_YARN, clientHost=sg1.imatiasl.lan, serviceCheckRole=null". Is this what is stalling the process?

Comment: "could not find role or or host to run check on," seems like a legitimate reason to stall. Like I said, networking problems, that's the worst part for server setup. And how many services are you installing that it takes any longer than maybe a couple hours on a fast network? (because Ambari downloads additional stuff)

Comment: Restart ambari server. The services have all finished installing. They just haven't started. By restarting ambari server it should clean up the process that is hung and you can then start the services yourself.

Comment: thanks, that did work :-)